# What’s eating the leaves of my bell pepper plant

Tags: leaves, pests

I am so shocked to see my Bell pepper plant this morning.

My bell pepper plant looks like this yesterday
[image: beautiful bell pepper plant]

When I checked it this morning it looks like this
[image: Bell pepper plant whole body]

[image: Bell pepper plant different angle]

[image: Bell pepper bitten leaf 1]

[image: Bell pepper bitten leaf 2]

[image: Bell pepper plant top view 1]

[image: Bell pepper plant top view 2]

My hunch is rats. But I’m not sure because the plant’s always been there, and so are the rats, and nothing’s eating it like so. Almost all of the leaves are gone in just a night. I also noticed that the surviving leaves are the topmost ones. Could this indicate the height of the eater?

Notes:

- this bell pepper plant is ~5months old and never bore any fruit yet
- the garden is situated  in a tropical country
- I am certain that there are no rabbits, mole and deer in the area

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the plants carefully, there might be caterpillars which camouflage, they would look like a part of the stem. I came across similar issue just today and could take out 6 of them after inspecting the plants.
Yoh might also come across tiny black group of dots on your leaves, not exactly sure what they are either poop or eggs, wipe them off.

Comment: That’s a lot of caterpillars on your plant! I never seen that many on a plant yet. I checked the leaves of my plant and there were no black group of dots. Hmm.. it also rained last night, I’m not sure if that have driven away the caterpillar/s because I did not see any as per today’s inspection. But thanks for the tip, ill surely keep that in mind.

Comment: They are very hard to see. Hornworms will eat the leaves and the peppers!